# Pandas describe vs scipy.stats percentileofscore with NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, percentile

I'm having a weird situation, where pd.describe is giving me percentile markers that disagree with scipy.stats percentileofscore, because of NaNs, I think.

My df is:

```
      f_recommend
0     3.857143
1     4.500000
2     4.458333
3          NaN
4     3.600000
5          NaN
6     4.285714
7     3.587065
8     4.200000
9          NaN
```

When I run `df.describe(percentiles=[.25, .5, .75])` I get:

```
       f_recommend
count     7.000000
mean      4.069751
std       0.386990
min       3.587065
25%       3.728571
50%       4.200000
75%       4.372024
max       4.500000
```

I get the same values when I run with NaN removed.

When I want to look up a specific value, however, when I run `scipy.stats.percentileofscore(df['f_recommend'], 3.61, kind = 'mean')` I get: 28th percentile with NaN and 20th without.

Any thoughts to explain this discrepancy?

ETA:

I don't believe that the problem is that we're calculating percentiles differently. Because that only matters when you're calculating percentiles of the same 2 numbers in different ways. But here, describe gives 25 percentile as 3.72. So there is absolutely no way that 3.61 can be 28th percentile. None of the formulas should give that.

In particular, when I use describe on the 6 values without NaN, I get the same values, so that's ignoring NaN, which is fine. But when I run percentile of score without the NaN I get a number that doesn't match.

ETA 2:

Simpler example:

```
In [48]: d = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])

In [49]: d.describe()
Out[49]: 
              0
count  7.000000
mean   4.000000
std    2.160247
min    1.000000
25%    2.500000
50%    4.000000
75%    5.500000
max    7.000000

In [50]: sp.stats.percentileofscore(d[0], 2.1, kind = 'mean')
Out[50]: 28.571428571428573
```

the "kind" argument doesn't matter because 2.1 is unique.

Comment: I've never gotten to the bottom of this, but I've also seen weird behaviour with describe returning mean values that are not even in the range of the underlying data. If I really care I usually operate directly on the numpy array to be safe.

Answer (score 5):

`scipy.stats.percentileofscore` does not ignore `nan`, nor does it check for the value and handle it in some special way.  It is just another floating point value in your data.  This means the behavior of `percentileofscore` with data containing `nan` is undefined, because of the behavior of `nan` in comparisons:

```
In [44]: np.nan > 0
Out[44]: False

In [45]: np.nan < 0
Out[45]: False

In [46]: np.nan == 0
Out[46]: False

In [47]: np.nan == np.nan
Out[47]: False
```

Those results are all correct--that is how `nan` is supposed to behave.  But that means, in order to know how `percentileofscore` handles `nan`, you have to know how the code does comparisons.  And that is an implementation detail that you shouldn't have to know, and that you can't rely on to be the same in future versions of scipy.

If you investigate the behavior of `percentfileofscore`, you'll find that it behaves as if `nan` was infinite.  For example, if you replace `nan` with a value larger than any other value in the input, you'll get the same results:

```
In [53]: percentileofscore([10, 20, 25, 30, np.nan, np.nan], 18)
Out[53]: 16.666666666666664

In [54]: percentileofscore([10, 20, 25, 30, 999, 999], 18)
Out[54]: 16.666666666666664
```

Unfortunately, you can't rely on this behavior.  If the implementation changes in the future, `nan` might end up behaving like negative infinity, or have some other unspecified behavior.

The solution to this "problem" is simple: don't give `percentileofscore` any `nan` values.  You'll have to clean up your data first.  Note that this can be as simple as:

```
result = percentileofscore(a[~np.isnan(a)], score)
```

Comment: NAN is actually a red herring. See my second 1-7 example.

Comment: Ah, yeah.  `percentileofscore([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], score, kind='mean')` returns the same value for any value of `score` where `2 < score < 3`.  In effect, it is a discrete function of `score`.  There is no value of `score` that returns 25.0.  (The same is true for the other `kind` options.)

Answer (score 0):

the answer is very simple.

There is no universally accepted formula for computing percentiles, in particular when your data contains ties or when it cannot be perfectly broken down in equal-size buckets.

For instance, have a look at the documentation in `R`. There are more than seven types of formulas! https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/quantile.html

At the end, it comes down to understanding which formula is used and whether the differences are big enough to be a problem in your case.

Comment: Right, so I understand why the kind = "mean" is necessary. But that doesn't explain why NaN is treated differently. It appears that NaN is treated as maxint or something, which is particularly surprising.

Comment: Also, pandas.describe doesn't seem to say what kind of percentile calculation it does, which is confusing.

Comment: Also, that only explains issues where the numbers are equal. The 25th percentile score that comes out of describe isn't 3.61, so that should be consistent.

Comment: bro, just look at the formulas if you want to make sure! good luck!

Comment: How do I find out what formulas describe is using? I can figure out percentileofscore, because it has kind='mean', but describe is less clear.

Comment: The downvote was because I didn't think you actually answered the question. However, at the moment I'm not actually sure. Will un-downvote when I have figured out what is going on.